# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'

Tags: sql-server-2005, syntax

When attempting to calculate an expression, I get the error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'.`

I'm not sure what is the error on this line:

```
(SUM([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] * [ICP].[UnitCost] )) - ((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS ) * @InputWeight ) OVER (PARTITION BY [ARC].[CustomerCode] )
```

I was able to use `OVER` on another expression and it worked just fine and was formatted like the one above, except it was only taking the `SUM` of one column.

Full Code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
DECLARE @PurchaseCost Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @InputWeight Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Prod_CostLBS Decimal(19,8);

SET @PurchaseCost = 2.58;
SET @InputWeight = 18100;
SET @Prod_CostLBS  = .15;

SELECT 
     CAST([ARC].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([ARC].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40)) AS [Supplier]
   , [PC].ProductCode
   , [PC].Description1
   , Count(IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Alt) AS [Boxes]
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
   , Sum(IC_ProductLots.OriginalQuantity_Stk) AS [Weight]
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
   , [ICP].UnitCost AS [Unit Cost]
   , Sum([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost]) AS [Total Sales]
   , Avg(([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] / [IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Alt])) AS [Avg. Box Weight]
   , Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] / @InputWeight) AS [Yield]
   , CAST (@InputWeight - SUM(Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])) OVER () AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS [Shrink]
   , Max(CAST ((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * @InputWeight AS DECIMAL (18,2))) AS [Cost]
   , SUM([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] * [ICP].[UnitCost]) - ((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * @InputWeight) OVER (PARTITION BY [ARC].[CustomerCode])
 AS [Profit]
 FROM (((( IC_Products [PC] 
    INNER JOIN  DC_Transactions [DCT] 
     ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey)
    INNER JOIN  AR_Customers [ARC] 
     ON [DCT].CustomerKey = [ARC].CustomerKey)
    INNER JOIN  IC_ProductLots 
     ON [DCT].LotKey = IC_ProductLots.LotKey)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
     ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5)
 WHERE 
    (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' }   AND (IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND ((1=1)  AND [ARC].CustomerKey IN (124) ) 
 GROUP BY 
     CAST([ARC].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([ARC].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40))
   , [PC].ProductCode
   , [PC].Description1
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
   , IC_ProductLots.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
   , [ICP].UnitCost
   , IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate
   , [ARC].CustomerKey
 ORDER BY 
     CAST([ARC].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([ARC].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40)) 
   , CAST (@InputWeight - SUM(Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])) OVER () AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
   , Max(CAST ((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * @InputWeight AS DECIMAL (18,2)))
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

Example Data for:

```
SUM([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] * [ICP].[UnitCost] 
- ( ( @PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS ) * @InputWeight )) 
OVER (PARTITION BY [ARC].[CustomerCode]) AS [Profit]

DCT.Quanity_Stk = 25
ICP.UnitCost = 3.50
PurchaseCost = 2.50
Prod_CostLBS = .50
InputWeight = 30

(25 * 3.50) - ((2.50 + .50) * 30) = -2.5
87.5 - (3 * 30) = -2.5
87.5 - 90 = -2.5
```

Comment: The SUM function does not reach all the way to the OVER expression.  Are you missing a set of parentheses after the SUM and before the OVER?

Comment: @Sako73 You're right, that gets rid of the error but it also throws off my calculation which is why I had the parens like that in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

```
SUM([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] * [ICP].[UnitCost]) 
    - ((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * @InputWeight) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY [ARC].[CustomerCode]) AS [Profit]
```

Is not correct syntax.

You can't stick arbitrary expressions between the aggregate and the `over`

Presumably you need

```
SUM([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] * [ICP].[UnitCost]) 
OVER (PARTITION BY [ARC].[CustomerCode]) 
- ( ( @PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS ) * @InputWeight ) AS [Profit]
```

If you are trying to adjust the result after the `SUM`.

Or

```
SUM([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] * [ICP].[UnitCost] 
- ( ( @PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS ) * @InputWeight )) 
OVER (PARTITION BY [ARC].[CustomerCode]) AS [Profit]
```

if you are trying to adjust the values that get summed.

Comment: The example you provide I'd say is the closest to what I've been trying to accomplish. However, I still get the wrong value. I tried adding SUM before purchase cost as well because I need the SUM of that whole equation. Any thoughts?

Comment: If I wasn't clear, I need the SUM of the quantity stock and unit cost and then I need to subtract that by the SUM of the purchase cost, prod cost, and input weight.

Comment: I have added example data to the question.